# Disabling an input device (keyboard, mouse) which is used in current session

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, device-driver, terminal-services

I'm developing a filter driver which works on top of an input device. Notably I'm testing it on my development machine (and yes, I know this is a bad idea).

On Windows XP whenever I needed to reload the filter driver, I'd just execute a batch file that would disable-enable the relevant devices through devcon, thus cause my filter driver to unload and reload.

However, on Windows 7 there seems to be a specific measure built against disabling the input device which your session is using. The option simply becomes unavailable in the Device Manager and even devcon no longer works. It *does* work from a remote desktop session, along with the kernel debug print "Trying to disable physical device not enabled in this session." (which hints that something explicit is allowing me to do this).

Is there a way to disable this functionality of Windows 7? Or perhaps a workaround you can offer to run my disable-enable batch file from an unrelated session?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sysinternals [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run dpinst.exe works around this limitation. (Not sure why, since the DpInst UI is still being displayed.)